# In generating a Linq to SQL class, how can I define a complex relationship?

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two views: one is a normal view built from one table with an integer ID and other columns for the record (let's call it View1).  I have another View (View2), which has an integer ID column and a second column named "table" (type: varchar).  That second column contains the name of the table to which the ID column is related:  So, if View2 contains an ID of 999 and its "table" column contains the value "View1", that means the record referenced is ID 999 from View1.

Far as I can tell, DBML only allows for one-to-one or one-to-many relationships based on explicit column references; I'd rather express the relationship as a one-to-one based on the ID column AND View1.table being equal to "View2".

Is this possible?  I know I can simply do an outer join in the linq query, but I'd rather avoid that if possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. The linq2sql mapper allows for mapping explicit foreign key relations, but if you don't actually have a foreign key relationship in the database, it's not possible for L2S to "infer" the relation in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and succinct answer, much appreciated.